# Ajax call to PHP is returning nothing

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make my first ajax example working on my MAMP.
my ajax.html looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='ajax.js'></script>
</head>
<body onload = 'ajax()'>
<div id='test'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my ajax.js looks like:

```
function ajax()
{
>>var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5

  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8888/ajax.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

my ajax.php looks like:

> echo 'hello world';

I detected response header from firebug:

> Response Headers
>   Connection  Keep-Alive
>   Content-Length  11
>   Content-Type    text/html
>   Date    Mon, 05 Nov 2012 18:57:46 GMT
>   Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=99
>   Server  Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.4.4
>   X-Pad   avoid browser bug
>   X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.4

but nothing in response text and nothing changed in my html.

Anyone could help me out please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to do a cross domain request. The browser prevents it due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

The standard solution is to set [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control) in your PHP to allow those requests.

For example :

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```

Comment: How can you possibly know this from the information given? I am asking out of curiosity by the way, not out of criticism.

Comment: Because of `("GET","http://localhost:8888/`. It's not probable that the PHP page is served on 8888.

Comment: AH, same-origin applies to port as well? TIL... Thank you.

Comment: It applies to port and it's worse : `file://` is like a kind of NaN : a page served in `file://` is not even the same origin as itself.

Comment: If I want to test my php code, it's better to get a remote php server right?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean but `localhost:80` and `localhost:8888` are different domains (for this problem) just like `otherdomain.com:80` and `localhost:8888`. So if I get correctly your question, you don't need to get another server.