# AJAX call the PHP script not outputting any results

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to update my list of tweets via AJAX.  I have ran the script on the page and know that script works, and I have a console.log line in my ajax call so I know that is getting hit as well.

```
    setInterval(function () {sendRequest()}, 5000);

    function sendRequest(){
        var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                console.log("yay");
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","getTweets.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

My AJAX should run every 5 seconds, and the hit the PHP script to return new results that have been stored in the database.  My PHP looks like:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "*", "*", "*");

if (!$conn) {
    echo("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM tweets;";

$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){

echo '<div class="tweet-containter">';

echo '<img class="user-img" alt="user-img" src="images/gb.png">';
echo '<h3 class="tweet-username">@'.$list['username'].'</h3>';
echo '<p class="tweet-body">'.$list['tweetBody'].'</p>';   
echo '<p class="tweet-body">Tweeted: '.$list['datePosted'].'Retweet: <i class="fa fa-retweet" id="retweet4" onclick="retweetAJAX()"></i> Like: <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" id="likes4" onclick="likeAJAX()"></i> Dislike: <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" id="dislikes4" onclick="dislikeAJAX()"></i></p>';

echo '</div>';

}
```

Comment: could be that it errored, so you should have a branch to handle when  xmlhttp.readyState==4 but xmlhttp.status is *not* 200 and print out that status so you can figure out the problem

Comment: @developerwjk I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  My if statement checks to make sure they are both what I want them to be.  And my string of "yay" is being printed to the console.  so the readystate is 4 and the status is 200.

Comment: what if the server had an internal error and returned status 500. you'd get readystate 4 status 500, and you're not printing anything on that so you wouldn't know

Comment: @developerwjk makes sense.  I revised my statement to looke like 

`if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    console.log("yay");
                }
                else if (xmlhttp.status==500){
                    console.log("Internal error");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }`

Comment: For an PHP file being used for AJAX you shouldnt be using mysqli error reporting. Thought i should mention that.

Comment: Remove the ; on your query, seeing how you dont have any excess queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes for those that do not understand ReadyState codes. You should know the following codes for ReadyState:

```
0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established
2: request received 
3: processing request 
4: request finished and response is ready
```

And Status Code

```
200: "OK"
404: Page not found
```

with that said, try doing this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
       if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
           console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
       } else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
          alert('There was an error 400')
       } else {
           alert('something else other than 200')
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay that words, however in my PHP script you'll see how I want to create a div.  However the response I'm getting from the sever is just plain text, example:
<div class="tweet-containter"><img class="user-img" alt="user-img" src="images/gb.png"><h3 class="tweet-username"> How would I get it to output a the like it does if I embed the PHP in the page?

Comment: all you have to do is set your content type: `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Answer (score 0):

ryandonohue,

PHP is a Hyper-Text Processor. PHP runs on your server & the results are generated before the page is loaded. You should not be using PHP to output results like HTML elements, it is much more appreciated if you use JavaScript to manipulate the Document Object Model (DOM).

Though, for your intermediate purposes you might not notice an immediate difference.

For PHP5 you should look into the usage of PHP-PDO http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php to prevent SQL injection.

Modification:

```
function getall($table, $values, $conditions = null, $limit = null, $ascdesc = null){
        $values_str = "";
        foreach($values as $key => $value){
            $values_str .= $value . ", ";
        }
        $cond_str = "";
        $hascond = false;
        if($conditions != null){
            $hascond = true;
            foreach($conditions as $key => $value){
                $cond_str .= $key . "='" . $value . "' AND ";
            }
            $cond_str = rtrim($cond_str, " AND ");
        }
        $values_str = rtrim($values_str, ", ");
        $cond_str = " WHERE (" . $cond_str . ")";


        $orderby = "";
        $hasorder = false;
        if($ascdesc != null){
            $hasorder = true;
            foreach($ascdesc as $key => $value){
                $orderby = " ORDER BY " . $value . " " . $key;
                break;
            }
        }


        $sql = "SELECT " . $values_str . " FROM " . $table . " " . (($hascond)? $cond_str: "") . (($hasorder)? $orderby: "") . (($limit)? " LIMIT " . $limit: "");
        //echo $sql;
        $sql_prep = (new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . 'database', 'username', 'Password'))->prepare($sql);
        $sql_prep->execute();
        return $result = $sql_prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }
```

initialization: ( returns an array so you need to json encode)

```
getall('table',
    Array(
          '*'
     ),
     null, 5, null);
```

AJAX:

```
function ajax(file,type, params, func){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                //xmlhttp.responseText
                func(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        if(type.toLowerCase() != "post"){
            xmlhttp.open(
                type, file + "?" + params_to_get(params),
                true
            );
            xmlhttp.send();
        }else{
            xmlhttp.open(
                type, file,
                true
            );
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send(params_to_get(params));
```

---

Since you have an error code of readystate of 4 with a status of 500 i would say the issue is more with the compatibility of MYSQLi or the way your table is set up with your database.

check out this POST for more information about headers:
[Ajax call to PHP is returning nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238781/ajax-call-to-php-is-returning-nothing?rq=1)